# Which sentence is correct (or more correct)?

Tags: adverb

Are the sentences below both correct and do they have same meaning?

> Er liest sehr gerne die Zeitung.
>   Er liest die Zeitung sehr gerne.

Comment: Unlike in English, you would usually omit the article ("die") when you are referring to newspapers in general, rather than a specific press or the copy lying in front of you: "Er liest sehr gerne Zeitung." However that doesn't work with the other sentence structure you suggested, so "Er liest die Zeitung sehr gerne" inevitably contains the implicit reference to "this particular newspaper".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both sentences are correct, but the emphasis is different.

The first sentence puts a small emphasis on *lesen*, whereas the second emphasizes *die Zeitung* a little more.

The difference is very subtle though and one can say (in a simplified manner), that these sentences are equivalent.